# 2001 AMC 12 Problems/Problem 8 | Why is the Slant Height 10?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

The problem says:

> Which of the cones listed below can be formed from a $252^\circ$ sector of a circle of radius $10$ by aligning the two straight sides?
>
> [image]
>
> (A) A cone with slant height of 10 and radius 6
>
> (B) A cone with height of 10 and radius 6
>
> (C) A cone with slant height of 10 and radius 7
>
> (D) A cone with height of 10 and radius 7
>
> (E) A cone with slant height of 10 and radius 8

I looked at this question, I'm not sure what I should be visualizing. If I connect the two blue lines, that should form a circle with radius 7. So, couldn't I make the height of the cone any value? What I'm visualizing is squashing the circle into a smaller one, then having a line coming out of the paper as a height. Why does the radius of the original circle become the height of the cone? I’m very confused.

Comment: Misha do you know the answer to the question or do you know someone who does because I don't want to waste my time with a question that's not going to be answered

Comment: You should basically never simultaneously post the same question here and at math overflow.  Under certain circumstances the same question can be addressed to both, but in that case there is still a delay between crossposts.

Comment: ok ill keep that in mind i just didn't want to have an unanswered question but in the future i wont do that

Comment: The picture shows a sector of a circle, with central angle $252^\circ$.  There are no "blue lines" so your attempt at solution makes no sense.  The idea is to visualize the result of "rolling up" the sector to form a cone, which will bring the two radii marked (as having length $10$) together to become the slant height of the cone.  You can work out the circumference of the cone by using the proportion of the central angle to a complete revolution, and this in turn tells you the radius of the cone's base.

Comment: sorry the blue lines were relevant on the actual website link to the amc problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the situation I faced when educating my son on this some years back. The solution - don't try to simply visualise it if you are having difficulty. Actually construct the shape and try folding it into a cone! And then you'll know exactly what's happening.

Any flat circular sector (which is basically like a circular pizza with a slice cut out of it) can be folded neatly into a three-dimensional right circular cone (without the circular base).

You will find that:

- it doesn't matter whether it's a minor sector (less than a semicircle) or a major sector (more than a semicircle) or even if it's exactly a semicircle. A cone can always be constructed. The centre of the sector will become the apex (peak or tip) of the cone. The smaller the sector, the more "peaky" the resulting cone. The larger the sector, the more "broad-based" the cone.
- the two radial edges of the sector become the slant height of the cone. The slant height is the length of the slanted edge measured from the base of the cone to its tip. It is not to be confused with the height of the cone, which is the perpendicular distance dropped from the tip of the cone directly through the centre of its base.
- the arc length of the sector becomes the circumference of the (open) circular base of the cone. This is the part a lot of students may find confusing. The sector, which is an incomplete circle folds to give a smaller complete circle (base of cone).
- the area of the sector is equal to the curved surface area of the cone.

So, in this case, the slant height is $10$ (equal to the radius of the sector) and the base radius can be computed using the arc length of the sector.

If the radius of the sector is $R$ and the central angle is $\theta$ in degrees, its arc length is $\frac{\theta}{360}(2\pi R)$.

If the base radius of the cone after folding is $r$, then you can equate the above expression to $2\pi r$.

Can you now complete the problem?

Comment: thank you Deepak!! I get why the slant height is 10. I don't think visualizing itself is a problem, I was just misunderstanding what to visualize or i guess what the question is asking. I thought that you would kind of squash the sector into a smaller circle, and then you could add any height you want out of the paper. Anyway, yeah I can answer the problem now. Thanks!

Comment: Most welcome, glad to have helped.